# CSV demographics analyzer seems to waste memory/move slowly

Tags: python, performance, memory-management, csv

I'm much more fluent in JS, but I needed to sort a lot of dates, ages, genders, etc. from a tab-delimited text file so I wrote this. Could I get some tips on how to make this more efficient and more Pythonic? The more Python I write the more I like it, but I *definitely* need some help.

One thing I noticed is that when I use a ~600 MB file Python uses up to 25% of my RAM. That seems like a bit much. Am I leaking somewhere? I couldn't make heads or tails of Guppy, which printed something like this:

```
Partition of a set of 8273952 objects. Total size = 1747556688 bytes.
 Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Kind (class / dict of class)
     0 414691   5 1389344200  80 1389344200  80 dict (no owner)
     1 7427576  90 338925432  19 1728269632  99 str
     2 414362   5  9944688   1 1738214320  99 float
     3    216   0  6847872   0 1745062192 100 list
     4   7040   0   580152   0 1745642344 100 tuple
     5     95   0   288488   0 1745930832 100 dict of module
     6   1917   0   245376   0 1746176208 100 types.CodeType
     7    235   0   243592   0 1746419800 100 dict of type
     8   1840   0   220800   0 1746640600 100 function
     9    235   0   209104   0 1746849704 100 type
<112 more rows. Type e.g. '_.more' to view.>
```

Which I'm *assuming* means that the dict is using 80% of my memory, and my variables are using 19%? The documentation is, uh, not incredibly user-friendly.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import division
import csv
import datetime
import subprocess
import gc

'''
#from guppy import hpy  # This is used only if you want to see where memory is allocated
#h = hpy()              # I woudn't uncomment unless you want to see your memory double
'''                     # Or if you want to see memory usage

vrdb = 'active.txt'

# Write headings to three output files

with open('legdata.txt', 'wb+') as myfile:
    myfile.write('LegDist,AvgAge,NumMales,PerMales,Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,Q5,Q6,NumFemales,PerFemales,Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,Q5,Q6' + '\r\n')

with open('citydata.txt', 'wb+') as myfile:
    myfile.write('City,AvgAge,NumMales,PerMales,NumFemales,Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,Q5,Q6,PerFemales,Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,Q5,Q6' + '\r\n')

with open('precinctdata.txt', 'wb+') as myfile:
    myfile.write('Precinct,AvgAge,NumMales,PerMales,NumFemales,Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,Q5,Q6,PerFemales,Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,Q5,Q6' + '\r\n')

with open('congressdata.txt', 'wb+') as myfile:
    myfile.write('CongressionalDistrict,AvgAge,NumMales,PerMales,NumFemales,Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,Q5,Q6,PerFemales,Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,Q5,Q6' + '\r\n')

def getCities():

    reader = csv.DictReader(open(vrdb, 'rb'), delimiter='\t')

    cities = []

    # Appends all the data from each person inside a specific city

    for row in reader:
        if row['RegCity']:
            cities.append(row.get('RegCity'))

    return cities

def getPrecincts():

    reader = csv.DictReader(open(vrdb, 'rb'), delimiter='\t')

    precincts = []

    # In Washington counties can use their own precinct codes which are the county code (e.g. King is KI) + precinct code + precinct part
    # To keep each unique we concat each part with a '+' -- this keeps the values separate but still unique

    for row in reader:
        if row['PrecinctCode']:
            precincts.append(str(row.get('CountyCode')) + '+'  + str(row.get('PrecinctCode')) + '+' + str(row.get('PrecinctPart')))

    with open('precincts.txt', 'ab+') as myfile:
        myfile.write(str(precincts))

def sortLists(function, output_file, shell_script):

    numcities = function
    numcities = str(numcities)

    with open(output_file, 'ab+') as myfile:
        myfile.write(numcities)

    subprocess.call([shell_script])

def getInformation(location, identifier, output_file):

    # Opens VRDB and parses it line by line

    reader = csv.DictReader(open(vrdb, 'rb'), delimiter= '\t')

    master_list = []
    ages = []
    nummale = 0
    numfemale = 0

    # Here we have the different quantiles
    # m denotes male, f denotes female

    fq1 = 0 # 18 - 25
    fq2 = 0 # 26 - 35
    fq3 = 0 # 36 - 45
    fq4 = 0 # 46 - 55
    fq5 = 0 # 56 - 65
    fq6 = 0 # 66 +

    mq1 = 0 # 18 - 25
    mq2 = 0 # 26 - 35
    mq3 = 0 # 36 - 45
    mq4 = 0 # 46 - 55
    mq5 = 0 # 56 - 65
    mq6 = 0 # 66 +

    if useprecincts != True:
        for row in reader:
            if row[location] == str(identifier):    
                master_list.append(row)

    if useprecincts:
        for row in reader:
            if str(row['CountyCode']) + '+' + str(row['PrecinctCode']) + '+' + str(row['PrecinctPart']) == identifier:
                master_list.append(row)

    # For each person in our specific LD/city/precinct, get their information and append it to the correct lists
    # 31556952 is used because it's the representation of 365.2425 days in seconds. 
    # 365.2425 is used because there's only 97 leap years every 400 years, not 100 (Gregorian calendar)
    # We also get the number of each gender

    for x,value in enumerate(master_list):
        dates = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.datetime.strptime(value['Birthdate'], '%m/%d/%Y')
        age = datetime.timedelta.total_seconds(dates) / 31556952
        ages.append(age)
        if value['Gender'] == "M":
            nummale += 1
            if 18 <= age < 26:
                mq1 += 1
            if 26 <= age < 35:
                mq2 += 1
            if 36 <= age < 45:
                mq3 += 1
            if 46 <= age < 55:
                mq4 += 1
            if 56 <= age < 65:
                mq5 += 1
            if 66 <= age:
                mq6 += 1
        if value['Gender'] == "F":
            numfemale += 1
            if 18 <= age < 26:
                fq1 += 1
            if 26 <= age < 35:
                fq2 += 1
            if 36 <= age < 45:
                fq3 += 1
            if 46 <= age < 55:
                fq4 += 1
            if 56 <= age < 65:
                fq5 += 1
            if 66 <= age:
                fq6 += 1

    # This defines the ages. Takes the sum of all the ages and divides it by the total values
    # It also takes the total number of each gender and divides that by the total
    # This gives us a percentage with 3 decimal places

    total_values = len(ages)
    average_age = sum(ages) / total_values

    perfemale = '{percent:.3%}'.format(percent=numfemale/total_values)
    permale = '{percent:.3%}'.format(percent=nummale/total_values)

    results = str(identifier) + ',' + str(average_age) + ',' + str(nummale) + ',' + str(permale) + ',' + str(mq1)+ ',' + str(mq2) + ',' + str(mq3) + ',' + str(mq4) + ',' + str(mq5) + ',' + str(mq6) + ',' + str(numfemale) + ',' +  str(perfemale) + ',' + str(fq1)+ ',' + str(fq2) + ',' + str(fq3) + ',' + str(fq4) + ',' + str(fq5) + ',' + str(fq6)

    # Prints output to console so we can see our script is working
    # `with... as myfile` appends each line to with \r\n so we can work with both unix and windows

    print results

    # h.heap() used to see where memory is allocated

    #print h.heap()

    with open(output_file, 'ab+') as myfile:
        myfile.write(results + '\r\n')

    gc.collect()    

# We define set useprecincts to false because we turn it to true later so we can use a modified for-loop to handle the precincts

useprecincts = False

# Gets Congressional District data

for e in xrange(1,11):
    getInformation('CongressionalDistrict', e, 'congressdata.txt')

# Gets Legislative District data

for r in xrange(1, 50):
    getInformation('LegislativeDistrict', r, 'legdata.txt')

# Gets city data

getCities()
sortLists(getCities(), 'citylist.txt', './shellsubprocess.sh')
listofcities = [line.rstrip() for line in open('citylist.txt')]

for i in listofcities:
    getInformation('RegCity', i, 'citydata.txt')
# Gets precinct data

getPrecincts()
sortLists(getPrecincts(), 'precinctlist.txt', './subshellprecincts.sh')
listofprecincts = [line.rstrip() for line in open('precincts.txt')]
useprecincts = True

# I'm passing 'a' because getInformation takes 3 args when I only need to pass two
# I suppose I *could* implement *args, but this works for such a simple scraper script

for c in listofprecincts:
    getInformation('a', c, 'precinctdata.txt')
```

Since I call two shell processes I'll include them here. (They're the same except with different file names). Yes, I know they could be better but they take seconds to run, are only run once a piece, and work. But if you want to you can critique them. They're incredibly simple though. **You can ignore this if you want**.

```
#!/bin/bash
touch precincts.bak;
cat precincts.txt | sed 's/, /\n/g' > precincts.bak;
cat precincts.bak | sed "s/'//g" > precincts.txt;
cat precincts.txt | tr -d '][' > precincts.bak;
sort precincts.bak | awk '!seen[$0]++' > precincts.txt;
exit
```

Comment: Are you sure your code works as shown? For example, you are calling `getCities()` which returns a list, without assigning it anywhere. In `sortLists` you seem to do `str(getCities)` which should result in something like `'<function getCities at 0xdeadbeef0000>'.

Comment: @otus it does... now. I've been running it for over 15 hours now (finding over 15,000 different precincts) but when I posted I remember I had fat-fingered my method call and forgotten to change this post. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: So could you fix the post to what's current?

Comment: @otus I did an hour ago ;)

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't notice you added the `()`, but you are still calling `getCities()` on the line before without using the return value.

Comment: @otus ah yeah I am. Shoot. That's an extra line that does nothing but slow my script.. Definitely need to remove it

Comment: It will be more clear if you remove some of the white lines. Use them sparingly, only separating blocks that belong together logically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite a few things you can do to make your code more Pythonic:

1. First off, look at [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Its the official Python style guide. It has a LOT of good Python coding practices.
2. Use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) whenever is feasible. Take your `getCities()` function. This can be written in two lines:

   ```
   def get_cities():
       reader = csv.DictReader(open(vrdb, 'rb'), delimiter='\t')
       return [row.get('RegCity') for row in reader if row['RegCity']]
   ```
3. Use `elif` instead of chaining multiple if statements. Currently in your `getInformation` function (and many other places), you have a long list of if statements. Each statement is getting processed even though each of the conditions are mutually exclusive (if `age` is between `18` and `26` then `age` **cannot** be between `26` and `35`).
4. Using string formatting instead of string concatenation. Though the performance benefits are debatable, string formatting is more Pythonic:

   ```
   # Instead of this...
   precincts.append(str(row.get('CountyCode')) + '+'  + str(row.get('PrecinctCode')) + '+' + str(row.get('PrecinctPart')))

   # Do this.
   precincts.append('{}+{}+{}'.format(row.get('CountyCode'),
                                      row.get('PrecinctCode'),
                                      row.get('PrecinctPart'))
   ```
5. Use `underscores_in_names` instead of `camelCase` or `noseparateratall`. The former bad formatting can be tolerated as it just goes against convention but is still readable. However the latter, which you use (`numcities`, `nummale`, `useprecinct`, etc.), is very hard to read.
6. As a follow-up to the previous point, make your names descriptive. As a reader, I have **no idea** what `vrdb` is supposed to do. I see that it holds a string, but what does that string supposed to do? What does it represent? It is better to be too *verbose* than too *terse*.

   This same point goes for function names. Make sure the name clearly represents the actions taken in the function. Your `getPrecincts` function is misleading. You grab all the precincts (expected) then you save them to a file (unexpected). Be as clear as possible.

---

There are other improvements I can suggest. However, implementing these will probably take some time. So I'll leave the rest to other reviewers.

Comment: Ahhh, I should have caught the if/elifs... The `'{}'.format(stuff)` is quite strange. I understand it, but it is still strange. Using `underscores_in_names` is going to be a tough one to get used to. In JS we use `camelCase` for our variables and functions. Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: For combining strings, the best way is to use `'+'.join((string1, string2...))`. It performs better because it avoids the use of temporaries. @eric_lagergren inside the `{}` you can put stuff to make the formating more powerful. For example, try `P is {P:2.f} - so {M}/{P}`.format(P=1./3, M=2)`

Answer (score 3):

Things I would have done (some minor) -

- I would order the imports alphabetically. (not a huge deal)
- You have a lot of "with open" statements in your code. I would have put this in a function. (again minor) i.e.

  ```
  # Formatting your strings like this allows you to be pep8 compliant - 79 chars 
  legal_data = (
      "LegDist,AvgAge,NumMales,PerMales,Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,Q5,Q6,NumFemales,"
      "PerFemales,Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,Q5,Q6"
      "\r\n"
      )

  def write_file(filename, mode, data):
      with open(filename, mode) as f:
          f.write(data)

  write_file('legdata.txt', 'wb+', legal_data)
  ```
- I typically use join for lines like this:

  ```
  precincts.append(str(row.get('CountyCode')) + '+'  + str(row.get('PrecinctCode')) + '+' + str(row.get('PrecinctPart')))
  ```

Comment: Agreed. I was more just trying to push the general idea of using a function, however let me update the function name for clarity. =)

Answer (score 3):

- To save memory you could use `namedtuple`s to hold data rows instead of `dict`s. [The documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields) includes an example of reading a CSV file.
- The program is slow because it makes many calls to `getInformation` that reads the large file every time. You could look for an approach where you collect information for, say, all the cities in one pass over the file.
- You would really benefit from using a database instead of the plain file. Databases are optimized for working with data that does not necessarily fit in RAM, and indexing supports efficient querying.

Comment: Regarding #2, I'm curious as to how that could be implemented. I'm sort of brainstorming here, but I'd need a way to store a value from one column based on the value from another column. My file can have up to 11,500 different potential identifying values, and I can't think of a reasonable way to store that in one pass...

Comment: @eric_lagergren You can read it once, and pass the reader to each function.